# subscript index notation select certain value

Tags: filtering, index, indexed-variable

I have an indexed variable `Subscript[p, s, m, t]` established using the Notation method. There are various expressions where `s`, `m`, `t` take on various integer values. I want to be able to select the parts of the expression where `m == 2`, for example. I tried the `Coefficient[]` function but it just produces 0.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no working example, I'll start by building a list of indexed variables:

```
samplelist = RandomSample[Flatten[Array[Subscript[p, #1, #2, #3] &, {3, 3, 3}]], 5]

(* {Subscript[p, 2, 2, 2], Subscript[p, 3, 3, 2], Subscript[p, 1, 2, 3],
    Subscript[p, 1, 3, 3], Subscript[p, 1, 3, 1]} *)
```

Selecting the elements for which `m = 2` (with `m` being the second index) is a straightforward case of pattern matching using [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Cases[samplelist, Subscript[p, _, 2, _]]

(* {Subscript[p, 2, 2, 2], Subscript[p, 1, 2, 3]} *)
```

Assuming your expressions are more complicated than that, you can use a similar approach for, say, a sum:

```
samplesum = samplelist.RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, 5]

(* -2 Subscript[p, 1, 2, 3] + 5 Subscript[p, 1, 3, 1] + Subscript[p, 1, 3, 3] + 
    3 Subscript[p, 2, 2, 2] + 4 Subscript[p, 3, 3, 2] *)

Cases[samplesum, _ Subscript[p, _, 2, _]]

(* {-2 Subscript[p, 1, 2, 3], 3 Subscript[p, 2, 2, 2]} *)
```

where the extra `_` is a pattern that can stand for any *Mathematica* expression; in this case, the integer coefficient on the relevant variables (so you could change the `_` to `_Integer` if you just wanted to get at all the variables with integer coefficients in an expression).

Note that `Cases` also has a *levelspec* argument. So, for example, if you just want to pull the variables (no coefficients) out of `samplesum`

```
Cases[samplesum, Subscript[p, _, 2, _]]
```

will just give you `{}`, but

```
Cases[samplesum, Subscript[p, _, 2, _], 2]
```

will return `{Subscript[p, 1, 2, 3], Subscript[p, 2, 2, 2]}`, as desired.

You can use [`TreeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeForm.html) to explore the levels that various subexpressions appear at. If you give some details about the expressions you're looking at, someone might be able to provide more specific help.